# Query Object as parameter for backend queries

Tags: c#

I am working on a library project, which is currently returning data from different sources (currently using Entity Framework but will be more than that in the future).

I created simple methods like:

```
public TransactionHistory GetTransactions(DateTime? dateFrom = null, DateTime? dateTo = null, TransactionTypes[] transactionTypes = null)
```

By the time the number of parameters started to grow and naturally I thought of creating a query model class and use it in the method parameters instead of using fields as parameters.

```
public class TransactionHistoryQuery
{
 public DateTime? dateFrom {get; set;}
 public DateTime? dateTo {get; set;}
 public TransactionTypes[] transactionTypes {get; set;}
}
```

And my method became this:

```
public TransactionHistory GetTransactions(TransactionHistoryQuery query)
```

But on various occasions, I have to make queries with greater than and less than operators in the backend (where dateFrom > [dateValue])

The first thing comes in my mind is the use of the query model like this:

```
public class TransactionHistoryQuery
{
 public DateTime? dateFromEquals {get; set;}
 public DateTime? dateFromGreaterThan {get; set;}
 public DateTime? dateFromLessThan {get; set;}

 public DateTime? dateToEquals {get; set;}
 public DateTime? dateToGreaterThan {get; set;}
 public DateTime? dateToLessThan {get; set;}
 ...
}
```

The second thought comes in my mind to use IQueryable but then I don't think mapping from IQueryable to IQueryable will work.

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, it's considered a bad practice to use optional arguments with default values for `public` library methods.

Comment: Optional arguments with the default value set to `null` are used so I can apply conditional queries on the backend. For example where statement for `dateFrom` field will only be applied on the backend repository when it has some value.

Comment: Please read this static code analysis [rule description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1026-default-parameters-should-not-be-used?view=vs-2019) why you shouldn't use optional arguments in `public` library signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use the `DateFrom` and `DateTo` properties. Keep the `Query` object as simple as possible and push the logic for the *greater/less than/equal/etc.* into the query itself.

```
// define classes
public class Transaction
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionHistoryQuery
{
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; } = null;
    public string Name { get; set; } = null;
}

// prep test data
IList<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
transactions.Add(new Transaction() { Name = "T1",TransactionDate = new DateTime(2010,10,19)});
transactions.Add(new Transaction() { Name = "T2", TransactionDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 13) });
transactions.Add(new Transaction() { Name = "T3", TransactionDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 3) });

// prepare query
TransactionHistoryQuery q = new TransactionHistoryQuery();
q.DateFrom = new DateTime(2017,1,1);
q.Name = "T";

// perform query and 'ignore' the null values in your query logic using conditions with parenthesis 
var result = 
    transactions.Where(t => (
                 (t.TransactionDate >= q.DateFrom  && t.TransactionDate <= q.DateTo) ||
                 (t.TransactionDate >= q.DateFrom && q.DateTo == null) ||
                 (q.DateFrom == null && t.TransactionDate <= q.DateTo)) &&
                 (t.Name.Contains((q.Name ?? string.Empty)) || q.Name == null)
                 ).ToList();

// results =  { Name = "T3", TransactionDate = new DateTime(2018, 12, 3) }
```